# Eclipse SWT: Display.syncExec() called from a synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I have a custom log that gets data printed by a background thread or by the main thread triggered by user mouse click event. The two thread may print on the log concurrently. Code is like this

```
public void appendLine(String s, int type) {
    synchronized (this) {
        int index = setInputLine(s);
        if (type == BG) {
            updateConsole();
        }
        else if (type == UI) {
            printConsole();
        }   
    }
}
```

Method setInputLines(), updateConsole() and printConsole() are not defined as synchronized. Method updateConsole() prints from background thread like this

```
public void updateConsole() {
    Display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
        // update widgets UI here
    });
}
```

However the above code logic failed in tests. Method appendLine() is called from a test background thread, and it always hang up at Display.syncExec() when the main thread tried to acquire the lock by calling appendLine() concurrently. Anybody knows why? Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the code in the `syncExec` is calling `appendLine`?

Comment: appendLine() is calling updateConsole(). updateConsole() calls Display.syncExec(). Problem is, if a background thread is calling appendLine(), then the main thread cannot call appendLine() concurrently. Otherwise program hangs up.

Comment: `syncExec` is a blocking call if anyone else is already calling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Display.syncExec` will block the thread calling it until it can be run - this will not be until the next time the UI thread calls `Display.readAndDispatch` in the main UI loop.

If the main UI thread calls `appendLine` before a `readAndDispatch` is run the UI thread will be blocked waiting for the `synchronized` block and you then have deadlock.

So it is not safe to call `syncExec` from within the synchronized block like this.

You might be able to use `asyncExec` instead of `syncExec` as this will not block the thread.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/206266/
Can you answer the last question of this post?